# Need help translating a Make File into Meson Build File for Vala

Tags: gtk, webkit, gtk3, vala, meson-build

I am working on an Application in Vala. I need to use both **webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0** and **webkit2gtk-4.0** in an single project.

I am following the example from - 
https://github.com/rschroll/webkitdom/tree/extension

The Make File from the example is as follows:

```
PKGS=--pkg gtk+-3.0 --pkg libsoup-2.4
EXEC=dom-test
SOURCES=dom-test.vala custom-web-view.vala
LIB_BASE=dom-server
LIB_SOURCES=$(LIB_BASE).vala
LIBRARY=$(LIB_BASE).so

# If you have webkit2gtk-4.0 installed, you will need a Vala from git
# version 6a1a1ab1 (2014/10/16) or later, in order to have the fixed
# .vapi files.
#WEBKIT_VAPI=--pkg webkit2gtk-4.0
#WEBKIT_EXT_VAPI=--pkg webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0
# Otherwise, use the -3.0 versions included here
WEBKIT_VAPI=--vapidir=. --pkg webkit2gtk-3.0
WEBKIT_EXT_VAPI=--vapidir=. --pkg webkit2gtk-web-extension-3.0 -X -I/usr/include/webkitgtk-3.0

all: $(EXEC) $(LIBRARY)

$(EXEC): $(SOURCES)
    valac $(WEBKIT_VAPI) $(PKGS) $^

$(LIBRARY): $(LIB_SOURCES)
    valac $(WEBKIT_EXT_VAPI) $(PKGS) --library=$(LIB_BASE) -X -fPIC -X -shared -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm $(EXEC) $(LIBRARY)
```

With Meson Build system, I tried to create a subproject with the shared library and link the shared library in the main project. But I am getting the error

```
DOMServer.vala:1.1-1.10: error: The root namespace already contains a definition for `WebKit'
```

The main project meson.build file as follows:

```
project('com.linappfoundry.athmanam', ['c', 'vala'])

domserver_proj = subproject('DOMServer')
domserver_lib = domserver_proj.get_variable('domserver_lib')

cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
m_dep = cc.find_library('m', required : false)

executable(
    meson.project_name(),
    'AthmanamApp.vala',
    'Widgets/MainWindow.vala',
    'Widgets/PoemParserWebView.vala',
    dependencies: [
        dependency('gtk+-3.0'),
        dependency('glib-2.0'),
        dependency('libsoup-2.4'),
    dependency('webkit2gtk-4.0'),
        dependency('json-glib-1.0'),
        dependency('libxml-2.0'),
        m_dep
    ],
    link_with: [domserver_lib],
    install: true
)
```

And subproject's meson.build file is as follows:

```
project('com.linappfoundry.athmanam.DOMServer', ['c', 'vala'])

domserver_lib = shared_library(
    'com.linappfoundry.athmanam.DOMServer',
    'src/DOMServer.vala',
    dependencies: [
        dependency('glib-2.0'),
        dependency('gtk+-3.0'),
        dependency('libsoup-2.4'),
        dependency('webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0')
    ],
    install: true
)
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, as I am new to both Vala and Meson.

Comment: Also check this out https://hub.packtpub.com/deploying-html5-applications-gnome/

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
DOMServer.vala:1.1-1.10: error: The root namespace already contains a definition for `WebKit'
```

is from the Vala compiler and is saying there is already a definition of `Webkit` in the global namespace. The error could be as simple as using a keyword with the wrong case, e.g. `Using Webkit;` when it should be `using Webkit;`.

`Webkit` is defined as a namespace in the global (root) namespace and that is done in the VAPI file. Try and find where it is being redefined as something else.

Comment: I have double checked. We cannot use webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0 and webkit2gtk-4.0, in a single project. So, I have to build the part of code that involved webkit2gtk-web-extension-4.0 as a shared library. The shared library builds fine, separately. But I want to use it as a subproject. Don't know whether it is possible with meson.

Comment: OK, I think I understand a little better. A WebKitWebExtension is a loadable module (see https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/stable/WebKitWebExtension.html). I guess this can only be loaded at run time so you can remove `link_with: [domserver_lib]` and just treat the shared module as another build artefact that is then loaded at run time. No need for a sub-project.